# how to counter Multiply times python

Tags: python, collections, counter

im new to python and have some questions want to ask

The question is how to counter multiply times

there are 6 dice stand

```
   import random
from collections import Counter

amt = 1
point = 0
diceStand = 6
dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
dice3 = random.randint(1,6)
dice4 = random.randint(1,6)
dice5 = random.randint(1,6)
dice6 = random.randint(1,6)
roll = [dice1,dice2,dice3,dice4,dice5,dice6]

print("Do you want to play a dice game?")
print("turn " , amt , " of 3")
print("You have", point,'point')
print("You Roll")

for k in range(1):
    print(roll)
    counts = Counter(roll)
    print (Counter(counts))
```

result :

```
[4, 1, 5, 6, 1, 4]
Counter({4: 2, 1: 2, 5: 1, 6*1})
```

how can i print message and Counter Multiply times
like 4*3 = 12 and 1*2 = 2
only more than 2 times will be multiply

then there are 4 dice already used

but you also can roll the remaining dice which is 2 dices for 1 time
then 12 and 2 will be save to the point 
after 3 attempt will be end of the game

really want to understand how to use the random value and counter 
Thank you

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. I feel there is a language barrier here. Maybe you can ask a friend with more experience in english language to help make your question more clear?

Comment: So you throw six dices and in the next round you throw only those dices that showed a number which was not shown by any other dice? the expected output is then the sum of all dices?

Comment: Sorry for the grammar, i cant even talk well in my first language.
i want to multiply the value with times
the like above
[4, 1, 5, 6, 1, 4]
Counter({4: 2, 1: 2, 5: 1, 6:1})
then 4*2 and 1*2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to print the product of any repeat dice rolls, e.g. if you roll a '2' four times, print "2 * 4  = 8"

If that's the case, then something like this could work:

```
import random

amt = 1
point = 0
diceStand = 6
dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
dice3 = random.randint(1,6)
dice4 = random.randint(1,6)
dice5 = random.randint(1,6)
dice6 = random.randint(1,6)
roll = [dice1,dice2,dice3,dice4,dice5,dice6]

print("Do you want to play a dice game?")
print("turn " , amt , " of 3")
print("You have", point,'point')
print("You Roll")

for i in range(1,7):
    total = 0
    for die in roll:
        if i == die:
            total += 1
    print i, " * ", total, " = ", i*total
```

Edit: here is an example output

```
Do you want to play a dice game?
('turn ', 1, ' of 3')
('You have', 0, 'point')
You Roll
1  *  1  =  1
2  *  0  =  0
3  *  2  =  6
4  *  2  =  8
5  *  1  =  5
6  *  0  =  0
```

Comment: by the way i also want to know 
how to say 
you have roll 1*1 = 1 
you have roll 3*2 = 6
you have roll 5*1 = 5

i only want 1*1 and 3*2 add to my point
thank you